# Vector space with $M^0 =\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\dim_K(V)= n >1$. What's the smalles $k \in \mathbb{N_0}$, so that $M \subset V$ with $k$ elements exists for $M^0 =\{0\}$?

Comment: Please clarify what the notation $M^0$ is supposed to mean. Also, you use $k$ to refer both to the field of $V$ as in $\dim_k(V)$ and the number of elements in your set $M$.  Presumably, these are not meant to be the same $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, $M^0$ refers to [the annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators) of $M$. If so, consider the following:

**Hint:** If $\dim (\operatorname{span}(M)) < n$, then $M^0$ contains a non-zero element.

Comment: So the answer is $k=n+1$?

Comment: @Chris that is not correct

Comment: Oh, then it has to be $k=n$?

Comment: @Chris That is correct